# use python's reduce method to group tweets into their hashtag, error setting key of array with string (name of hashtag)

Tags: python, flask, tweepy

I am very new to python. I am trying to turn a list of tweets returned from twitter api into a grouped list (by hashtag). I decided to use reduce method but my issue is that python won't allow me to create string based keys as property:
Here is the data example

a tweet

```
{
 created_at: date
 id: number
 text: string
 entities: {
  hashtags: []
  urls: []
 }
}
```

Next up is the code, notice that first I do a filter to remove any tweets that do not have hashtags, probably this is what is setting the 'array' as List.

```
tweets_copy = []
for tweet in tweets:
    tweets_copy.append(tweet._json)

tweetsWithHashtags = filter(lambda tweet: len(tweet['entities']['hashtags']) > 0, tweets_copy)

def groupPostByHashtag(r, a):
    firstHashtag = a['entities']['hashtags'][0]['text']
    r[firstHashtag] = r[firstHashtag] or []   #KeyError: '5200mAh'  this is the hashtag name
    r[firstHashtag].append(a)
    return r

results = reduce(groupPostByHashtag, tweetsWithHashtags, {})
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `r[firstHashtag] or []`, do `r.get(firstHashtag, [])`
`KeyError` is raised when a non-existent key is accessed in a dictionary using the square brackets syntax.
By using [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method, you can prevent error by providing a default value.

Btw, you can also use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to create the desired dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for tweet in tweetsWithHashtags:
    hashtags = tweet['entities']['hashtags']
    for ht in hashtags:
        result[ht].append(tweet)
```

Comment: Wow thanky you, all I had to do was:

1. use r.get(firstHashtag, []) as advised
2.  set defaultdict(list) for the reducer's initiatng value